# Error while WAS 7 installation

Tags: java, websphere

I'm getting below error while WAS 7 installation . Please suggest what could be possible cause .

C:\Users\Banand4\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp2_was.7000.wasdev.nocharge.windows.amd64.zip\WAS..\JDK\jre.pak\repository\package.java.jre\java\jre\lib\ibmjsseprovider2.jar (The system cannot find the file specified.)
(Mar 7, 2014 1:38:25 PM), Process, com.ibm.ws.install.ni.ismp.mediaspanning.InstallNIFMaintenanceMediaSpanning, err, The file java/jre/lib/ibmjsseprovider2.jar could not be replaced.
(Mar 7, 2014 1:38:25 PM), Process, com.ibm.ws.install.ni.ismp.mediaspanning.InstallNIFMaintenanceMediaSpanning, err, com.ibm.ws.install.ni.framework.NIFException: The file java/jre/lib/ibmjsseprovider2.jar could not be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the installation as Administrator.